# Roaming Folder in Metro app pointing to Local\*\*\RoamingState

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

I want to store app settings in Roaming Folder. (Settings are very small ~2KB).

I am storing in ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder folder. 
The above is pointing to *`C:\Users\Tilak\AppData\Local\Packages\b5dea8e0-504c-4105-8b4c-6d2da32816f7_vbe7xwj32evkc\RoamingState`*

I am surprised why the above location is pointing to User\Local folder and not User\Roaming.

ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder is pointing to *`C:\Users\Tilak\AppData\Local\Packages\b5dea8e0-504c-4105-8b4c-6d2da32816f7_vbe7xwj32evkc\LocalState`*.
Also, What additional steps needs to be followed for sync'ing  multiple device on same live account using Roaming storage.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am surprised why the above location is pointing to User\Local folder and not User\Roaming.

This is because User\Roaming is used for user profiles roaming within a Domain. [Roaming User Profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roaming_user_profile). 
It has nothing to do with Roaming feature of Windows 8 Metro style apps.

> What additional steps needs to be followed for sync'ing multiple device on same live account using Roaming storage.

Nothing. Just set the data to Roaming storage and it will be available across devices albeit with some time lag (not real time synchronization).

Answer (score -1):

Additionally, UWPs are sandboxed and cannot read or write files outside of their

```
C:\Users\Tilak\AppData\Local\Packages\b5dea8e0-504c-4105-8b4c-6d2da32816f7_vbe7xwj32evkc\RoamingState
C:\Users\Tilak\AppData\Local\Packages\b5dea8e0-504c-4105-8b4c-6d2da32816f7_vbe7xwj32evkc\LocalState
C:\Users\Tilak\AppData\Local\Packages\b5dea8e0-504c-4105-8b4c-6d2da32816f7_vbe7xwj32evkc\TempFolder
```

equivalent folders, unless the user selects it in the file picker.

This restriction is ostensibly for security reasons; if you want access to the traditional AppData folder, write a desktop app.